# How to generate multivariate normal data in R?

Tags: r

I'm completing an assignment, in which I have to generate a sample X = (X1, X2) from a bivariate normal in which each marginal is N(0,1) and the correlation between X1 and X2 is 0.5.

I think the way to approach this is to use the mvrnorm function, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed after that. Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14):

Indeed, the `mvrnorm` function from the MASS package is probably your best bet. This function can generate pseudo-random data from multivariate normal distributions.

Examining the help page for this function (`??mvrnorm`) shows that there are three key arguments that you would need to simulate your data based your given parameters, ie:

- `n` - the number of samples required (an integer);
- `mu` - a vector giving the means of the variables - here, your distributions are standard normal so it will be a vector of zeros; and
- `Sigma` - a positive-definite symmetric matrix specifying the covariance matrix of the variables - ie, in your case, a matrix with variance on the diagonal of ones and covariance on the off-diagonals of 0.5.

Have a look at the examples in this help page, which should help you put these ideas together!

Answer (score 10):

Here are some options:

1. `mvtnorm::rmvnorm` and `MASS::mvrnorm` work the same way, although the `mvtnorm::rmvnorm` function does not require that you specify the means (i.e., the default is 0). Giving names to the `mu` vector will specify the names of the simulated variables.

```r
n <- 100
R <- matrix(c(1, 0.5,
              0.5, 1), 
            nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
            
mu <- c(X = 0, Y = 0)
mvtnorm::rmvnorm(n, mean = mu, sigma = R)
MASS::mvrnorm(n, mu = mu, Sigma = R)
```

2. `simstandard::sim_standardized` will make standardized data only, but will do so with less typing:

```r
simstandard::sim_standardized("X ~~ 0.5 * Y", n = 100)
```

Comment: For me, mvtnorm returns "Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘mvrnorm’", although mvrnorm works.

Comment: The indentation in your R matrix can be misleading: matrices are filled by columns and not by rows. Make sure to use `byrow = TRUE` if your cov matrix is not symmetric and you want your code to reflect the matrix. Here it's fine obviously!

Answer (score 4):

Using base R (no package needed) and a bit of statistics:

```r
Sigma = matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,1), ncol=2)
R = chol(Sigma) # Sigma == t(R)%*%  R
n = 1000
X = t(R) %*% matrix(rnorm(n*2), 2)

X %*% t(X)/n # test
```