# How to generate multivariate data with circle and w dependencies among variables in R

Tags: r

I am interested in generating multivariate data (with 4 variables) where the dependencies
among variables are either circle or W shapes (similar to the correlation shapes in this page][1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation)).

In another word, I would like to generate data with 4 variables, with the dependencies as follows:

1- The correlation between Var_1 and Var_2 is circle shape.

2- The correlation between Var_2 and Var_3 is W shape.

3- The correlation between Var_3 and Var_4 is gaussian.

Is there a possible way to generate such data in R?

Comment: I'm not sure but this link might help:
https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/02/multivariate_data_with_r.html
or this one maybe:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997925/how-to-generate-multivariate-normal-data-in-r/60189160

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Thanks a lot. I know how to simulate a normal distribution. But I do not know how to generate the data where the dependencies among them have a circle shape, for example.

Comment: Oh I understand. My friend Anil may have your answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something on these lines

```r
# for circle pattern (say around 1000 variables)
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
theta <- runif(n/2, 0, 2*pi)
Var_2 <- append(cos(theta), cos(theta)) * 200
Var_1 <- append(sin(theta), -sin(theta))

plot(Var_1, Var_2)
```

[image]

```r
#for w pattern
Var_3 <- cos(Var_2/(n %/% 30)) + rnorm(length(Var_2),0,0.2)

plot(Var_3 ~ Var_2, type='p')
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. It is a great help. I really appreciate it. Thanks again.